# Why "window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)’).matches === false" when chrome is still in dark mode?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My computer is macOS Monterey(version 12.6.7) and has Google Chrome Version 121.0.6167.184 (Official Build) (x86_64)

I’m trying to detect whether Chrome is in dark mode by javascript.

(1) I set Chrome in dark mode.

(2) Open a new tab in Chrome whose address bar is empty .

in console:

`window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')`

returns:

```
MediaQueryList {
    media: '(prefers-color-scheme: dark)',
    matches: true,
    onchange: null
}
```

"matches: true" is expected since chrome is in dark mode.

(3) In address bar, type in https://translate.google.com/

in console:

`window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)')`

returns:

```
MediaQueryList {
    media: '(prefers-color-scheme: dark)',
    matches: false,
    onchange: null
}
```

why "matches: false" when chrome is still in dark mode?
[image]

I expect to see

`window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)’).matches === true`

when chrome is in dark mode regardless of whether address bar is empty or not.

Comment: I reckon it's because your system is not running in dark mode.

Comment: @SigurdMazanti: by "system", you mean "system preferences" in MacOS? 
But `window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)’)` should refer to settings in Google Chrome instead of "system preferences" in MacOS, right?

Comment: "*by "system", you mean "system preferences" in MacOS?*" - yes, exactly. I'm not exactly sure how it works but I ran into a similiar issue recently where it prioritized my system settings over Chrome.